# Getting ActiveCell value in excel FROM word macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to manipulate an excel workbook from word. Everything was working quite well until all of a sudden I couldn't get a response from ActiveCell.Value

The problem is happening all the way at the bottom of this block of code where I try to show the value in a msgbox but no msgbox comes up.

The previous commands such as:

```
worksheetJobs.Activate
```

and

```
.Cells(1500, fichierColumn).Select
```

are working fine.

The weird thing is that I was working on this (there is a whole block of code that comes AFTER what I have posted) and then all of a sudden I couldn't get even this very basic thing to respond...

```
    Dim excelObj As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook

    'If Excel is running, get a handle on it; otherwise start a new instance of Excel
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err Then
        MsgBox "excel is not running"
        Set excelObj = New Excel.Application
        excelObj.Visible = True

        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
        Set oWB = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=todoWorkbook)

    Else
        MsgBox "excel is running"
        Dim wb As Workbook
        For Each wb In excelObj.Workbooks
            If wb.Name = toDoName Then
                Set oWB = wb
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wb
    End If

    MsgBox oWB.Name

    Dim fichierColumn As Integer
    Dim outMots As Integer
    Dim outLignes As Integer
    Dim langOut As Integer

    fichierColumn = 5
    outMots = 17
    outLignes = 18
    langOut = 9

    Dim worksheetJobs As Excel.Worksheet
    Set worksheetJobs = oWB.Worksheets("Liste jobs")
    worksheetJobs.Activate

    With worksheetJobs
        .Cells(1500, fichierColumn).Select
        Dim tempStr As String

        tempStr = ActiveCell.Value
        MsgBox tempStr

    End With

    'Set excelObj = Nothing
    'Set oWB = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
   MsgBox todoWorkbook & " caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
       "Error: " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't getting a value in the message box for a couple of reasons.  You're almost there with your cell referencing but `ActiveCell` is a property of the `Excel.Application`.  VBA thinks `ActiveCell` comes from the Word object model, not Excel's because you don't explicitly specify it's from Excel.

Since one of your first lines is `On Error Resume Next` all your errors are being surpressed and you aren't hitting the error of the unqualified reference to `ActiveCell`.   Consequently word is passing the blank string of `tempStr` to your message box.

The following will work for you

```
tempStr = excelObj.ActiveCell
```

It should be noted that you do not need to `Select` cells in order to get their values.  The following will produce the same result:

```
tempStr = worksheetJobs.Cells(1500, fichierColumn).Value
```

Comment: Thanks, that completely solved the problem. you're a life saver!